# How to emit an event from HttpInterceptor in the angular 5

Tags: angular, events, service

I'm trying to send an event from HttpInterceptor.

Code of my events service:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class Message {
    constructor( public name:string, public data:any){    
  }  
}

export class NotifyService {
dispatcher: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {}

emitMessageEvent(name:string, data:any){
  let message = new Message(name,data);
  this.dispatcher.emit(message);
}

getEmitter() {
  return this.dispatcher;
}
```

A component that receives events

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { NotifyService } from './services/notify.service';


@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ NotifyService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  subscription: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private notifyService: NotifyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.notifyService.getEmitter()
      .subscribe(item => this.showAppLevelAlarm(item));
  }

  private showAppLevelAlarm(_notify: any): void {
    // this.message = _notify.msg;
    console.log(_notify);
  }
}
```

And my HttpInterceptor:

```
import { NotifyService } from '../services/notify.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(public notifyService: NotifyService) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(req).do(event => {
  return event;
},
error => {
  this.notifyService.emitMessageEvent('showAppLevelAlert', error.error);
})
```

Help me understand why the events that were sent from the HttpInterceptor are not received by the AppComponent. But if I send an event from another component, the AppComponent receives an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this wrong, first of all Event Emitter shouldnt be a go to method for watching changes as explained here in

http://blog.bogdancarpean.com/how-to-watch-for-changes-an-arrayobject-on-angular-2/

You should rather use localstorage or sessionstorage to store your data in interceptor (as they are global in nature) and then recieve changes to them using doCheck lifecycle hook in Angular

I use my interceptor for appending Authorization Tokens and detecting whether I should display the loading bar,

Here is my code

interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class IndInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(evt => {
      localStorage.setItem('loading','Y');
      if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
        localStorage.setItem('loading','N');
        console.log('---> status:', evt.status);
        console.log('---> filter:', req.params.get('filter'));
      }
    });

  }
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck{
   public loading; 
   ngDoCheck(){
       this.loading = localStorage.getItem('loading');
       console.log(this.loading);
   }
}
```